# Azure DevOps Error 401 Account not authorized to view this page

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft365

Although there's a similar question on SO, but it didn't resolve my issue.

I created a project in Azure DevOps with my Microsoft365 account (work account name@company.com). Then I invited my client to that project (name2@company2.com). **It worked initially** but now it's throwing **Error 401**. Not authorized to view this page.

When she logins on Project URL, it **makes her login 2 times which is strange**. I tried incognito, clearing cache, removing cookies, different browsers, everything.

She **got a mail initially** when I invited but now I removed her from project and invited again, but **no invitation email is going to her email again**.

More info: She has added our work emails on her Microsoft 365 Teams, SharePoint with her work email.

What can be the issue? Any tips to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Azure DevOps Error 401 Account not authorized to view this page

You can try the following two ways to see  if that account can access the organization.

1.Please try to access https://aex.dev.azure.com/ with that account and change domain to see if your organization lists here. Then confirm he is locating in the correct directory which is your AAD owned.

For example, `Microsoft` is the directory that my company's AAD owned. Then I must located in this directory so that I can access the work organizations successfully:

[image]

2. Check if the external user on different domain who is trying to access the project is there in active users in admin center ( https://admin.microsoft.com), if by any chance it's in deleted users, restore that user to active users.

3.Sign out completely from Azure DevOps by completing the following steps. Closing your browser might not sign you out completely. Sign in again and select your other identity:

1. Close all browsers, including browsers that aren't running Azure
   DevOps.
2. Open a private or incognito browsing session.
3. Go to this URL: https://aka.ms/vssignout.
   You see a message that says, "Sign out in progress." After you sign
   out, you're redirected to the Azure DevOps @dev.azure.microsoft.com
   webpage. If the sign-out page takes more than a minute to sign you out, close the browser and continue.
4. Sign in to Azure DevOps again. Select your other identity.

---

*If all of above does not work for this account. Since stackoverflow is a open forum and not secure to share some org and account info, I'd suggest you share your issues [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). Then attach your `organization name`, `AAD name`, `issue account` there.*

Comment: Hi Leo. In my account dropdown on aex.dev.azure I can see my company and her's. But in her account, only her company is visibile. I tried creating a different project and inviting her again, but shes not getting the invitation on her email. Tried logging by Point 3 in answer, didnt resolve.

Comment: I have requested the client to open a support ticket on microsoft 365 admin center. Will update when the issue gets resolved.

Comment: Hi Leo. Found out the issue. Need to test now. The problem was that user had an email of firstname.lastname_domain#EXT#mydomain.onmicrosoft.com which looked like a junk email. So someone deleted it to add proper email like firstname.lastname@domain.com but found out that, thats how microsoft saves external users. Restored the user now from deleted users.

Comment: Hi Leo, was waiting to test it with client. Thankfully It's resolved after restoring the soft deleted users.

Answer (score -1):

Create an account with Outlook and try inviting outlook mail members. It will work, this is due to azure will allow only outlook people or they should be in same organisation (for example they should have same domain email id : clinton@hiok.com)

Comment: I have already mentioned the resolution. The error was something else in my case.